# How can I move the input button to the right?

Tags: html, css

I have a html defined like this

```html
<table style="margin: auto;">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="85%">
        <col width="85%">
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td> ...... </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>        
        <td><input type="submit" value="Add Log" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

At the moment, the button stays at the left. How can I move it to the right?

Comment: Have you tried `float: right`?

Answer (score 1):

#### CSS

```
td.right {text-align: right;}
```

#### HTML

```
<td class="right"><input type="submit" value="Add Log" /></td>
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vWVjQ/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no width specified to your table so it is fit to the table width now.

Add `input{float:right}` to css or `align="right"` to the direct td

Like `<td align="right"><input type="submit" value="Add Log" /></td>`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wS5Rs/1/)

Comment: actually  I have set <table style="margin: auto;">
<col width="85%">
<col width="85%"> simply change td align to right doesn't work, becasue the button moves to middle right, not far right

Comment: In that case you should post your proper code with respective css. Then we can check the proper problem

Comment: sorry, I failed to notice the the col tag in the colgroup

Answer (score 0):

```
[type=submit]{

    margin-left: 121px;
    margin-top: 19px;
    width: 84px;
    height: 40px;   
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:700;

}
```